# itextSharp null value showing &nbsp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, gridview, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create a pdf from a gridview. When there is a null value in the table the pdf places a &nbsp in its place. How do I remove this and show the null value? I do know the pdf is created after the gridview is already populated however is there a way to tell it that nulls should show as blanks? My code is as follows:

```
Protected Sub btnPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPDF.Click

    Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells.Count)

    For Each headerCell As TableCell In grdResults.HeaderRow.Cells
        Dim font As New Font()
        font.Color = New BaseColor(grdResults.HeaderStyle.ForeColor)

        Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(headerCell.Text, font))
        pdfCell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(grdResults.HeaderStyle.BackColor)
        pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)
    Next

    For Each gridViewRow As GridViewRow In grdResults.Rows

        For Each tableCell As TableCell In gridViewRow.Cells
            Dim font As New Font()
            font.Color = New BaseColor(grdResults.RowStyle.ForeColor)

            Dim pdfCell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(tableCell.Text, font))
            pdfCell.BackgroundColor = New BaseColor(grdResults.RowStyle.BackColor)
            pdfTable.AddCell(pdfCell)
        Next

    Next

    Dim pdfDocument As New Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F)
    pdfDocument.SetPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate())
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocument, Response.OutputStream)

    pdfDocument.Open()
    pdfDocument.Add(pdfTable)
    pdfDocument.Close()
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment, filename-results.pdf")
    Response.Write(PdfDocument)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you literally seeing the HTML-like entity `&nbsp` or are you just seeing spaces? Also, not related to your problem but remove the line `Response.Write(PdfDocument)` because it doesn't do what you think it does. That line actually calls `ToString()` on the `pdfDocument` but that object doesn't have a string representation so you're getting junk data. It works 99% of the time but occasionally you'll get a corrupt PDF if you keep doing that.

Comment: I am literally getting '&nbsp' in the cell field when the value is blank in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that I was receiving the &nbsp in the pdf came from calculated fields. When there was no value for the calculation it would not put anything in the gridview cell so in turn it would put the blank space value in the pdf. I went back to the calculations and if a value was not determined than I placed a space for the value. For instance -

```
        If dtRaw.Rows(0).Item("ParameterName").ToString() <> "NOY" Then
            drCalcRow("NAAQGreater") = iNAAQS
            drCalcRow("NAAQGreater80") = iNAAQS80
        Else
            drCalcRow("NAAQGreater") = " "
            drCalcRow("NAAQGreater80") = " "
        End If
```

It works however it adds a lot to the code. It would be nice to have something one time that would check when it loops through the rows as it writes the pdf. I have tried a couple of things but nothing worked or even made an impact.